Append charset=utf-8 to a line that contains "text/<any text" where it doesn't already exist
I'm trying to use regex in a bash script to add charset=utf-8 to any line that contains "text/whatever", if it doesn't already exist. So that the line then look exactly like "text/whatever; charset=utf-8", and it does this for every line that matches the pattern and doesn't already have charset=utf-8.
I've tried the following and many iterations of it:
'/mimetype.assign/,/)/ s/\(text\/.*\)\(.*\)\(charset=utf-8\)\{0\}/\1\2 charset=utf-8\"\,/'
The outputs i keep getting from this and variations of it is not correct. This is some of the output I'm getting from using sed.js.org:
 ".png"          =>      "image/png",
  ".xbm"          =>      "image/x-xbitmap",
  ".xpm"          =>      "image/x-xpixmap",
  ".xwd"          =>      "image/x-xwindowdump",
  ".css"          =>      "text/css; charset=utf-8", charset=utf-8",
  ".html"         =>      "text/html", charset=utf-8",
  ".htm"          =>      "text/html", charset=utf-8",
  ".js"           =>      "text/javascript", charset=utf-8",
  ".asc"          =>      "text/plain;charset=utf-8", charset=utf-8",
  ".c"            =>      "text/plain;charset=utf-8", charset=utf-8",
  ".cpp"          =>      "text/plain;charset=utf-8", charset=utf-8",
  ".log"          =>      "text/plain;charset=utf-8", charset=utf-8",
  ".conf"         =>      "text/plain;charset=utf-8", charset=utf-8",
  ".text"         =>      "text/plain;charset=utf-8", charset=utf-8",
  ".txt"          =>      "text/plain;charset=utf-8", charset=utf-8",
  ".spec"         =>      "text/plain;charset=utf-8", charset=utf-8",
  ".dtd"          =>      "text/xml", charset=utf-8",
  ".xml"          =>      "text/xml", charset=utf-8",
  ".mpeg"         =>      "video/mpeg",
  ".mpg"          =>      "video/mpeg",

You'll notice that it is adding it to the lines that don't have it but its not configured properly. Its also adding it to the lines that already have it and also misconfiguring it anyways. Maybe I'm over complicating it and there's a simpler regex cmd I can use.
The example below is a chunk of the file I'm trying to change. You'll notice that some of the lines that contain "text/whatever" are already configured properly
##  MimeType handling
## -------------------
##
## Use the "Content-Type" extended attribute to obtain mime type if
## possible
##
mimetype.use-xattr        = "disable" 

##
## mimetype mapping
##
mimetype.assign             = (
  ".ogg"          =>      "application/ogg",
  ".wav"          =>      "audio/x-wav",
  ".gif"          =>      "image/gif",
  ".jpg"          =>      "image/jpeg",
  ".jpeg"         =>      "image/jpeg",
  ".png"          =>      "image/png",
  ".xbm"          =>      "image/x-xbitmap",
  ".xpm"          =>      "image/x-xpixmap",
  ".xwd"          =>      "image/x-xwindowdump",
  ".css"          =>      "text/css; charset=utf-8",
  ".html"         =>      "text/html",
  ".htm"          =>      "text/html",
  ".js"           =>      "text/javascript",
  ".asc"          =>      "text/plain;charset=utf-8",
  ".c"            =>      "text/plain;charset=utf-8",
  ".cpp"          =>      "text/plain;charset=utf-8",
  ".log"          =>      "text/plain;charset=utf-8",
  ".conf"         =>      "text/plain;charset=utf-8",
  ".text"         =>      "text/plain;charset=utf-8",
  ".txt"          =>      "text/plain;charset=utf-8",
  ".spec"         =>      "text/plain;charset=utf-8",
  ".dtd"          =>      "text/xml",
  ".xml"          =>      "text/xml",
  ".mpeg"         =>      "video/mpeg",
 
# make the default mime type application/octet-stream.
  ""              =>      "application/octet-stream",

Thanks in advance for the input.

Do you have to use sed? awk is much better when you have to test multiple line conditions, e.g. /required/ && !/prohibited/ to match lines that contain required but don't contain prohibited.

I'm open to any suggestions to be honest to get the file properly configured and formatted.

If the line already has some other charset, do you want to replace it with charset=utf-8?

So I'm basically looking for just these guys
`".html"         =>      "text/html",
".htm"          =>      "text/html",
and trying to make them into ".html"         =>      "text/html;charset=utf8",
".htm"          =>      "text/html;charset=utf8",

I understand that. But if it contains text/plain;charset=windows-1852 should that be replaced with text/plain;charset=utf-8 or left alone?

im sorry, misunderstood. anything that has "text/xxxxxxx", should be configured to "text/xxxxxx; charset=utf-8", and only that. So youre example above of text/plain;charset=windows-1852, should be changed to text/plain;charset=utf-8

Use ! after the address specification to exclude lines that already contain charset=utf-8.
Then change your pattern so it stops matching at the " character.
sed '/charset=utf-8/!s#\("text/[^;"]*\)[^"]*#\1; charset=utf-8#'

Explanation:

/charset=utf-8 matches lines with that string.
! inverts the match so we don't process those lines
\("text/[^;"]*\)[^"]* matches from "text/ up to the next " character, capturing everything before ;..
\1; charset=utf-8 replaces this with the captured part followed by ; charset=utf-8.

In the replacement string & is replaced with the part of the line that matched the regular expression.

Thank you. Well Done. My attempts look like alphabet soup compared to this. Can you give me a short break down of the sed command.

I've added explanation, and also tweaked the command after some testing.

You don't need the /charset=utf-8/! since if it's present it'll just be replaced with the same string anyway.

@EdMorton I realized myself that after writing the code, but decided to leave it in to  express the OP's intent.

It's also useful to see the logic of how to make changes to lines that don't match a pattern. In this case the pattern happens to match the result, but not always.
